# Windows 10, can't add printer, get 'local print server is not running'

Tags: windows-10, printer, network-printer, print-spooler

I had a DLink router with a print server to which my printer was attached. I got a new TP-Link router and tried to set up the print server there, but after a number of unsuccessful attempts, ended up setting it up on an ethernet port on the router.

In the process, somehow my print spooler has gotten messed up. In Settings, the printer shows up as 'driver is unavailable' (I did install the driver). If I try to add a new printer, I get 'Windows can't open Add Printer. The local print spooler service is not running. Please restart the spooler or restart the machine.'

I've tried both restarting the spooler and rebooting the machine, but the problem persists.

I ran services.msc and it shows the print spooler with a startup type as automatic but the service status is stopped.  Started it again, it says it's running, I go back to add printer, get the 'can't open Add Printer' message again.  Rerun services.msc, and it shows the spooler as no longer running.

I got copies of spoolsv.exe and spoolss.dll from another computer where printing is working, but even though I'm an administrator, I can't replace the old copies, and I can't seem to do anything to change that.  I've tried running netplwiz, but it won't let me change any of the permissions.

Right now I'm out of ideas on what to try next. Printing works fine from two other computers on the network, just not on this one.

Answer (score 0):

(This may be a partial answer.)

The print spooler service may be starting then immediately stopping if there are corrupt print jobs in the queue. Fix this as follows:

1. Navigate to:

   ```
   c:\windows\system32\spool\printers
   ```
2. Delete any files in this folder.
3. Restart the Print Spooler service.

---

*I got copies of spoolsv.exe and spoolss.dll from another computer where printing is working, but even though I'm an administrator, I can't replace the old copies, and I can't seem to do anything to change that.*

**Don't do this.** This is not your problem. The Print Spooler is a victim in your situation, not the cause.

If you are concerned about system file corruption or version mis-matches, run `sfc /scannow` to have Windows find and resolve any such errors.

Comment: Let me know what difference, if any this makes and I may be able to expand my answer if it is only a partial solution.

Comment: Thank you.  I had tried deleting the files in that folder and it made no difference.  I have to go out, but I'll try running the sfc /scannow when I get back.

Comment: I just ran the scan and it didn't find any problems.